# Can't draw infowindows with google maps on swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I build an application for iOS that shows a map and differents markers, each one have to display on click a custom infowindow.

Everything works fine, the map display my location and the markers display the default infowindow but if I implement the flollow code to make custom infowindow:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    // 1
    NSLog("Marker infowindow es llamada")
    //let index:Int! = Int(marker.accessibilityLabel!)
    // 2
    let customInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomIW", owner: nil, options: nil) as! CustomIW
    customInfoWindow.Nombre.text = marker.title
    customInfoWindow.direccion.text = marker.snippet
    return customInfoWindow
}
```

I get the warning "Cast from '[AnyObject]!' to unrelated type 'CustomIW always fails'", and when i run the app, it crashes at the line of the loadNibName function.

CustomIW.xib is the name of my custom InfoWindow view, and CustomIW.swift is the name of the class of my Custom infoWindow, the class only have the two conections to the two values that i want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
    ... dNibNamed("CustomIW", owner: self.view, options: nil) as! CustomIW
```